# Laravel Mailable public members not available in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Laravel 5.3.26

I have a very basic Mailable that I just can't get to access view data.

This is how I call the Mailable:

```
    $lead = new \App\Lead;
    $lead->email = $request->email;
    //...other assignations here...
    $lead->save();

    \Mail::to($lead)->send(new \App\Mail\LeadSubscribed($lead));
```

This is the mailable:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LeadSubscribed extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $lead;

    public function __construct(\App\Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->lead = $lead;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.subscribed');

    }    
}
```

According to the docs, the $lead variable should be available in the view since it is a public member.

But my view:

```
@extends('emails.layout')

{{ dd($lead) }}
```

Fails:

```
ErrorException in 5dce710c76367c58a43c4cc55d425b0f31847f8d.php line 1:
Undefined variable: lead (View: MY_PATH\resources\views\emails\subscribed.blade.php)
```

I think I tried everything, using with() (even if it shouldn't be required), displaying all variables, nothing works, the view never sees any variables.

I'm obviously doing something worng, but I can't figure out what is it.

Comment: you are not returning '$lead' to the view so of course the variable will be undefined

Comment: @Phorce The docs says public members of a Mailable are automatically available. But even when using ->with() to force it, it is not available.

Comment: I think it should `$this->lead`

Comment: @NewbeeDev Doesn't work.

Comment: Does `dd($lead)` in the constructor show the data?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I think you are onto something, it looks like the constructor is never called. Scratching my head here...

Comment: I think what you need it `View::share('lead',$lead);` https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Thanks to @AlexeyMezenin for pointing me in the right direction : I WAS DEBUGING THE WRONG CODE :( The emails are actually working just fine ($lead IS available because it is a public member) but the code that was crashing was the "web view" of that email, wich is a normal view call to which I wasn'T passing any params. DOH !